# Is it possible to modify HTTP/2 headers with a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, http, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to modify the request headers of a specific site using the declarativeNetRequest API.

```
//background.js

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
  addRules: [
    {
      id: 1000,
      action: {
        type: "modifyHeaders",
        requestHeaders: [
          { header: ":path", operation: "set", value: "/doodles" },
        ],
      },
      condition: {
        urlFilter: "google.com/search",
        resourceTypes: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "other"],
      },
    },
  ],
  removeRuleIds: [1000, 100, 1],
});
```

It only works if 'header' doesn't have the colon in front, which is the HTTP/2 header I need to modify (:path). Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: Probably a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Do you know if there could be any practical reason for it? If not I guess I'll submit a report.

Comment: MV3 has a lot of bugs, it's pretty low-quality overall.

Comment: I think the extension I'm trying to build inadvertently falls under the 'ad-blocking' category, and it seems like Google is trying to handicap ad-blocking with declarativeNetRequest. I think I'm just going to give up and go back to v2 even though I won't be able to publish.